# is there a way to decode values inside a column

Tags: spotfire, tibco

we need to do decode('utf-8') a column using python script or any method.IS there any workaround for that?
The scenario is following.
we are writing back to oracle database.But we got a new issue that writing back is not properly working when we write Chinese or Korean or any such languages. So what we are trying is we encode this to utf-8 using python script and write it to DB and then we need to decode it in spotfire while displaying it in spotfire.
much appreciated

Comment: Downvoted. Have you even tried or looked into what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

`NameEncode()` and `Base64Endcode()` are available in Spotfire.